# Why does "Preparing SD card" message appear on Optimus One P500 3-4 times a day?

Tags: external-sd, lg-optimus-one

On my Optimus One P500 it shows.

```
Preparing SD card
```

The above message shows at least 3 to 4 times in a day.

During this Apps on SD cards are automatically closed.
Any files opened(Music/PDF) as not accesible.

Is this a issue with me or Optimus or android 2.2

Comment: Update: The problem had gone after I hard reset the device. I assume it was some application which was offending. I have the list of application previously installed on App Brain. I will try to find the culprit and update.

Comment: Hello  guys,

I have similar problem on my LG P500. From time to time the phone just stack (you can't touch and do anything). After ~ 1 minute phone is restarted. 

Does anybody figure out the root cause of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is resolved with the new update available from LG

Comment: What update? 2.3?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that was fixed by formating the card in the phone.

Settings -> SD card & phone storage settings -> Unmount SD card. Then format the card on the same screen.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem with 2.2 in general, although it may be specific to 2.2 on the Optimus.  (Did you ever have 2.1?)  This should normally only happen when the SD card is manually dismounted from the phone settings or by connecting the device to a computer.  It might be an app causing this problem -- you could use Titanium Backup to "freeze" your apps one by one until you hopefully discover the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this might happen if the SD card is losing its connection, although that would be more troubling.

Have you checked to ensure that the SD card is well-seated in its slot?

(This assumes, of course, that you can access the card.)

Another worrying possibility is a flaw with the card itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that this is not a random error. It occurs with some sd cards when you touch the proximity sensor of the phone. The screen becomes black and inactive and then the sd card is removed from the phone. I hope this will help to solve the issue